# Javascript setTimeout keeps running

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add the **class is-ending** with a setTimeout delay however I can see that it keeps running even if I click other buttons.

- I add class is-ending with setTimeout()
- I remove the class is-ending and add a clearTimeout.

What the best way to achieve that? my code works but the clearTimeout doesn't stop the clearTimeout.

```
toggleContent(inputEl, contentEl) {
        const maxValue = inputEl.closest('.frequency-selector-block').dataset.maxValue;


        if (inputEl.value === maxValue) {

//add class to content if successfull otherwise remove it



            setTimeout(function () {
                contentEl.classList.add("is-visible");
            }, 1500);
          
        } else {
                contentEl.classList.remove("is-visible");
        }
    }


setCorrectText(inputEl, inputRangeContainer, selectionText) {
        const inputValue = Number(inputEl.value);
        let myTimeout;

        if (inputValue < 1) {
             //if value of the input range is 0 delete set timeout

            clearTimeout(myTimeout);
            inputRangeContainer.classList.remove("is-ending");
            inputRangeContainer.classList.add("is-starting");
            
            selectionText.innerText = selectionText.dataset.option1Text;
        }

        if (inputValue >= 1 && inputValue <= 2) {
             //if value of the input range is 1 delete set timeout

            clearTimeout(myTimeout);
            inputRangeContainer.classList.remove("is-starting"); 
            inputRangeContainer.classList.remove("is-ending");  
            selectionText.innerText = selectionText.dataset.option2Text;
        }

        if (inputValue > 1) {
            inputRangeContainer.classList.remove("is-starting");

            myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                inputRangeContainer.classList.add("is-ending");
            }, 1500);
             
            selectionText.innerText = selectionText.dataset.option3Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're probably setting multiple timeouts, and you can only clear the last one because you're only saving the id of one in `myTimeout`…

Comment: @deceze what are you suggesting?

Comment: @user173420 deceze is suggesting that you're probably setting multiple timeouts...

Comment: I notice that in the case where inputValue is 2 it would clear the timeout and then immediately set another one. Is that your intention?

Comment: @ADyson Don't put words in my mouth. … I'm suggesting they're probably setting multiple timeouts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `setCorrectText` is called, `let myTimeout` redeclare `myTimeout` as `undefined`, so `clearTimeout(myTimeout)` equals to `clearTimeout(undefined)`, timer created before can never be stopped. delcare `myTimeout` as property of `inputRangeContainer` will fix the problem.

```
setCorrectText(inputEl, inputRangeContainer, selectionText) {
    const inputValue = Number(inputEl.value);
    // let myTimeout;

    if (inputValue < 1) {
         //if value of the input range is 0 delete set timeout

        clearTimeout(inputRangeContainer.myTimeout);
        inputRangeContainer.classList.remove("is-ending");
        inputRangeContainer.classList.add("is-starting");
        
        selectionText.innerText = selectionText.dataset.option1Text;
    }

    if (inputValue >= 1 && inputValue <= 2) {
         //if value of the input range is 1 delete set timeout

        clearTimeout(inputRangeContainer.myTimeout);
        inputRangeContainer.classList.remove("is-starting"); 
        inputRangeContainer.classList.remove("is-ending");  
        selectionText.innerText = selectionText.dataset.option2Text;
    }

    if (inputValue > 1) {
        inputRangeContainer.classList.remove("is-starting");

        inputRangeContainer.myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            inputRangeContainer.classList.add("is-ending");
        }, 1500);
         
        selectionText.innerText = selectionText.dataset.option3Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain why this would solve the problem...

Comment: @ADyson ok, I have updated my post

Comment: @emptyhua thanks for providing the above!
I've got another bit that I thought It wouldn't count I've added above on my question.

Comment: @emptyhua on the if (inputEl.value === maxValue) { I have another set timeout that checkes if the function is successuf or not. Could you please help?

Comment: delcare timer as property of inputEl `inputEl.xxTimer = setTimeout` `clearTimeout(inputEl.xxTimer)`

Comment: @emptyhua where shall I place the clearTimeout(inputEl.myTimeout); ? the class is not beight added

Comment: if you do not need to clear the timer, just `setTimeout` without assignment is fine

Comment: @emptyhua nope because that adds the class and the doesn't stop if I click somthing else

Answer (score 2):

`myTimeout` is a local variable to the `setCorrectText` function.
With the way your function is written, your timeout is never going to get cleared. Because when the if blocks that could eventually clear it are executed, `myTimeout` is undefined.

I suggest you store your timeouts in a property of your class, or in an object that is passed as a parameter of the `setCorrectText` function, instead of a local variable.